# Center a static width vertical submenu under a dynamic horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I've been at this for hours. I can find individual components of what I want, but I can't seem to throw them together.

The issue I am having is that I can't get the static width submenus to center on the li items they are derived from. This should be easy if those parent li items had static widths, but I would like to dynamically changed their widths based on how wide the page is. I don't know if this is visually pleasing, but it is something I would like to do and don't want to make static. I would make the widths 100%, but they tend to look dumb when the page gets really wide (the reason why I chose them to be static)

I'm sure there are other changes I should make to the css structure as well to make it nicer, so if you have any tips please throw them to me!

This is what I have.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ede2gsc6/

The html:

```
<ul id="top-menu">
    <li>ITEM1</li>
    <li>ITEM2
        <ul>
            <li>SUBITEM1</li>
            <li>SUBITEM2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ITEM3
        <ul >
            <li>SUBITEM1</li>
            <li>SUBITEM2</li>
            <li>SUBITEM3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ITEM4</li>
    <li>ITEM5
        <ul>
            <li>SUBITEM1</li>
            <li>SUBITEM2</li>
            <li>SUBITEM3</li>
            <li>SUBITEM4</li>
            <li>SUBITEM5</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
body, ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


#top-menu{
    float: left;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,240,255,.5);
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0px;   
    margin: 0px;
    min-width: 620px;
    list-style: none;   
}
        #top-menu li {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
            width: 20%;
            list-style: none;
        }
        #top-menu a:hover {
            color: #00F0FF;
        }
            #top-menu li ul {
                padding-top: 1px;       
                position: absolute;
                background: rgba(0,240,255,.5);
                border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                border-left: 1px solid black;
                border-right: 1px solid black;
                visibility: hidden;
                width: 170px;
            }
            #top-menu li:hover ul {
                visibility: visible;
                display: block;
            }   
                #top-menu li ul li {
                    float: left;
                    padding: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: left;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
left: 50%;
margin-left: -85px;
```

on you `#nav li ul` to generate that center positioning. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ede2gsc6/3/

Comment: This is the method i was trying to get working, but I couldn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to make this a bit more dynamic you may as well use classes as opposed to id's.

Here is an example with classes that has what you require. 
http://jsfiddle.net/54n1r96e/1/

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>ITEM1</li>
<li>ITEM2
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>SUBITEM1</li>
        <li>SUBITEM2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>ITEM3
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>SUBITEM1</li>
        <li>SUBITEM2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>ITEM4</li>
<li>ITEM5
    <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>SUBITEM1</li>
        <li>SUBITEM2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! What do you mean by making it more dynamic, like expanding it in the future? And could you explain why I couldn't just use an ID for the top level ul, and break down into the `#nav li ul` instead of using the drop down classes? Seems like unnecessary tags that just increase readability.

Comment: An id can only be used once. That same drop down class can now be used elsewhere apart from your nav.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work.

- I moved the ul-item 50% to the right by applying a margin of 50%. So the ul starts halfway ITEM1, ITEM2, etc.(uncomment the borders in the Fiddle if you want to see where it is)
- After that I moved the li-items within the ul 50% of its width to the
  left. This means the middle of the li is now at the left side of the
  ul. So the li-items are centered
- Using width: 100% on the li items of the submenu will give all those items the same width (that of the longest menu item)
- The rest all has to do with styling the li-items to make them appear as the ul that normally surrounds them.

Check out the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ede2gsc6/4/)** to see the result and read the comments in the code. Here is the code I added/modified:

```
            #top-menu li ul {
                padding-top: 1px;
                margin-left: 50%;
                position: absolute;
                background: rgba(0,240,255,.5);
                /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;
                border-left: 1px solid black;
                border-right: 1px solid black;*/ /*remove comment tags if you want to see where the actual ul is*/
                visibility: hidden;
                width: auto;/*set width to fit content*/
                background-color: transparent;
            }
            #top-menu li:hover ul {
                visibility: visible;
                display: block;
            }   
                #top-menu li ul li {
                    float: left;
                    padding: 5px 5px;
                    width: 100%;/*set width to the longest item in li so all li items have equal width*/
                    clear: both;
                    text-align: left;
                    border-right: 1px solid red;
                    border-left: 1px solid red;
                    margin-left: calc(-50% - 6px);/*unfortunately a calc function is needed here because adding padding/borders to the left moves the entire block to the right.*/
                    margin-top: -1px;/*solves issue of submenu disappearing when hovering over border*/
                    background-color: purple;
                }
#top-menu li ul li:last-child{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;/*add border to the bottom of the last li-item*/

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, seems as though the other solutions are a bit more elegant though! =)

Comment: Yes they are easier, but they rely on width being preset in the code (which I assumed you didn't want after reading your question), where my example adapts to the width of the li-items. That aside the centering-technique used by Tyson is basically the same as mine.

Comment: From my understanding of the question, he wants submenus with a static width. That's why I came up with the quick `left` and `margin-left` positioning. Of course not _that_ dynamic :)