# How do I center a menu option under it's heading option in a drop down menu?

Tags: html, css

My menu comes up as:

```
   MENU ITEM 1 | MENU ITEM 2 | MENU ITEM 3

   ..........MENU Stuff  | ....MENU Stuff  | MENU Stuff
```

And so on.

I want it to show:

```
   MENU ITEM 1 | MENU ITEM 2 | MENU ITEM 3

   MENU Stuff.....| MENU Stuff .. | MENU Stuff
```

How do I get it to center under the heading option?
It's a bit of a mess, but I think this is all of the coding which relates to my menu.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>Home</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Menu 1
    <ul>
        <li>Stuff</li>
        <li>More stuff</li>
        <li>And more</li>
    </ul></li>
<li>Things
    <ul>
        <li>More</li>
        <li>Today</li>
        <li>Ideas</li>
    </ul></li>
```

CSS

```
ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: -50px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 420px;
}
ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
}
li {
    width: 110px;
}
ul#menu li a{
    display: inline;
    background:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li a:hover{
    width:120px;
    color: black;
    background:white;
}
ul#menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */
}
ul#menu li:hover ul li {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: please add your code..

Comment: It's nearly impossible to come up with the best answer without knowing the structure of the elements. The best you'll get is guesswork, and here's mine - if the submenu is `ul`, add `left: 0;` to its style.

Comment: You might want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26748569/center-a-static-width-vertical-submenu-under-a-dynamic-horizontal-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add padding in ul because the default of ul element add padding to the left

```
ul#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    padding:0;
}
```

then add this

```
ul#menu li ul li {
    text-align-left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it:-

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/29hv50wy/)**

```
ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
    /*margin-top: -50px;*/
    text-align: right;
    /*margin-left: 420px;*/
    float:right
}
ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    text-align:left;
}
li {
    width: 110px;
}
ul#menu li a{
    display: inline;
    background:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li a:hover{
    width:120px;
    color: black;
    background:white;
}
ul#menu li ul {
    display: none;
        padding:0;
    margin:0;
        float:left

}
ul#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */

}
ul#menu li:hover ul li {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

**[Another DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/LyL9h52a/)**

```
ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
   margin-top: -50px
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: 420px;
}
ul#menu li {
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
}
li {
    width: 110px;
}
ul#menu li a{
    display: inline;
    background:white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li a:hover{
    width:120px;
    color: black;
    background:white;
}
ul#menu li ul {
    display: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
ul#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block; /* display the dropdown */
}
ul#menu li:hover ul li {
    background: white;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px;
}
```